# The Ever Amplifying Zigzag

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, number

Write a program or function that takes in a positive integer N and outputs the first N numbers of this amplifying zigzag pattern, using only the lines needed:

```
                                         26
                                       25  27                                      .
         10                          24      28                                  .
        9  11                      23          29                              .
 2     8     12                  22              30                          44
1 3   7        13              21                  31                      43
   4 6           14          20                      32                  42
    5              15      19                          33              41
                     16  18                              34          40
                       17                                  35      39
                                                             36  38
                                                               37
```

So, if N is `1` the output is

```
1
```

If N is `2`, the output is

```
 2
1
```

If N is `3` the output is

```
 2
1 3
```

If N is `4` the output is

```
 2
1 3
   4
```

If N is `10` the output is

```
         10
        9
 2     8
1 3   7
   4 6
    5
```

If N is `19` the output is

```
         10
        9  11
 2     8     12
1 3   7        13
   4 6           14
    5              15      19
                     16  18
                       17
```

and so on.

## Notes

- Each peak or trough of the zigzag reaches its point one more line away from the line with the `1` on it than the previous peak or trough.
- N is not limited to `44`. The zigzag grows in the same pattern and larger N should be supported.
- Numbers with multiple digits should only "touch" at their corners, as depicted. Make sure this works when N is `100` and above.
- There should be no empty (or space only) lines in the output except one optional trailing newline.
- Any line may have any amount of trailing spaces.

## Scoring

The shortest code in bytes wins. Tiebreaker is earlier answer.

Comment: What's the maximum possible N?

Comment: @JuliePelletier In theory there is none, but you can assume it will be less than 2^16.

Comment: Is using [control characters](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5124/12012) allowed or are we limited to digits spaces and linefeeds?

Comment: @Dennis Let's say no. Just digits/spaces/newlines.

Comment: Somebody should submit that to the OEIS in that format as a joke.

Answer (score 10):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>41</s> <s>37</s> 29 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
RDµḌ’½Ċ-*_\x©L€Ṣ.ị®ạ€⁶ẋj"FZj⁷
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=UkTCteG4jOKAmcK9xIotKl9ceMKpTOKCrOG5oi7hu4vCruG6oeKCrOKBtuG6i2oiRlpq4oG3&input=&args=NDQ)

#### How it works

```
RDµḌ’½Ċ-*_\x©L€Ṣ.ị®ạ€⁶ẋj"FZj⁷  Main link. Argument: n (integer)

R                              Range; yield [1, ..., n].
 D                             Decimal; yield A =: [[1], ..., [1, 0], ...].
  µ                            Begin a new, monadic chain. Argument: A
   Ḍ                           Undecimal; convert back to falt range.
    ’                          Decrement to yield [0, ..., n-1].
     ½Ċ                        Take the square root and round up (ceil).
       -*                      Elevate -1 to each rounded square root.
         _\                    Cumulatively reduce by subtraction.
                               This yields [1, 2, 1, 0, -1, 0, ...], i.e., the
                               vertical positions of the digits in A.
             L€                Compute the length of each list in A.
           x                   Repeat the nth position l times, where l is the
                               nth length.
            ©                  Copy the result to the register.
               Ṣ               Sort.
                .ị             At-index 0.5; yield the last and first element,
                               which correspond to the highest and lowest position.
                  ạ€®          Take the absolute difference of each position in the
                               register and the extrema.
                               This yields the number of spaces above and below
                               the integers in r as a list of pairs.
                     ⁶ẋ        Replace each difference with that many spaces.
                         F     Flatten the list A.
                       j"      Join the nth pair of strings of spacing, separating
                               by the nth digit in flat A.
                          Z    Zip/transpose the result.
                           j⁷  Join, separating by linefeeds.
```

Comment: Why not make a function in your language (Jelly) that can do that in a few chars while you're at it?

Comment: @JuliePelletier The art of writing a good golfing language is about coming up with a set of instructions (and syntax/language semantics) which allow you to write short solutions for as many different tasks as possible, not about being able to solve one very specific and contrived challenge in a single byte. A good golfing language tends to be actually very powerful and expressive, as opposed to just being a collection of built-ins which are useless for anything but the specific function they compute.

Comment: @JuliePelletier And it would also go against the rules of PPCG SE

Answer (score 8):

## PHP, <s>211</s> <s>177</s> <s>164</s> 163 bytes

Predict the peaks with `$n` and increase the array dynamically in either direction, using `($x, $y)` output cursor.

Numbers are aligned with `str_pad()` and the final output is the `implode()` of that array of strings (`$g`).

```
for($x=0,$d=-1,$h=$n=2,$y=$a=1;$a<=$argv[1];$y+=$d){$g[$y]=str_pad($g[$y],$x).$a;$x+=strlen($a);if($a++==$n){$h+=2;$n+=$h-1;$d*=-1;}}ksort($g);echo implode(~õ,$g);
```

### [Test it online!](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a8ca8a253713c3e241570f710f8ed8f76f75d507)

Update: removed 34 bytes by getting rid of the unneeded array_pad().
Update2: followed @insertusernamehere's advice to shorten it a bit more.
Update3: followed @Lynn's advice to save one more byte with ~õ which imposes the use of LATIN-1 charset. (not available in online PHP emulator so not included there)

Comment: Just a question about this code.. Don't you have to initialize the array $g before you access a specific element? I mean, giving it a length or inserting the rows? I'm not very experienced with PHP, so it just looks weird to me... Thanks.

Comment: No.  Once you define `$arr = [];`, you can refer to `$arr[anything]`.  Some cases will output notices but those are ignored here.  Note that reading stuff like this probably won't help you much to learn a language.  Your comment made me realize I could make it shorter though as I initially thought I'd need to pad my array but I don't.  :)

Comment: Haha glad for helping ;) Just realized that in PHP an array and a dictionary are initialized in the same way and are completely the same when looking at the syntax (Why, PHP?!)

Comment: Some minor improvements – *164 bytes*: `for($x=0,$d=-1,$h=$n=2,$y=$a=1;$a<=$argv[1];$y+=$d){$g[$y]=str_pad($g[$y],$x).$a;$x+=strlen($a);if($a++==$n){$h+=2;$n+=$h-1;$d*=-1;}}ksort($g);echo implode("⏎",$g);` (Replace ⏎  with an actual newline.)

Comment: I believe if you set up your encoding right (Latin-1, not UTF-8), [`~õ` is a two-byte alternative](http://golf.shinh.org/reveal.rb?join+lines/clock_1318394696&php) to `"⏎"`.

Comment: @Lynn:  insertusernamehere's suggestion was to use an actual LF instead of `"\n"` to save a byte.

Comment: Looks kinda neat if the output is very large and wraps: http://i.imgur.com/chkGb1e.png

Comment: @Julie: Right! But `"⏎"` with a real LF is three bytes long, while `~õ` is even shorter at two bytes. It’s a bitwise-negated bareword ([example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0fb01f8464dbe764ff6b6caa7de9b5967844ae4e)) consisting of only the byte `0xF5`. Negated, that becomes `0x0A`, a newline character. (PHP is really messed up. :D)

Comment: @Lynn:  I certainly wasn't expecting that but it's a neat trick to save a byte.

Answer (score 8):

## Pyth, <s>60</s> <s>53</s> <s>52</s> <s>46</s> <s>42</s> <s>39</s> <s>38</s> <s>36</s> <s>34</s> <s>32</s> 31 bytes

39: It is now on par with [the bug-fixed version of Jelly](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/82866/48934), and I have out-golfed Dennis' competing version!

38: I have out-golfed Dennis!

36: I have out-golfed Dennis again!

34: Even lower than his bug-fixed version!

31: 32 -> 31 thanks to Dennis.

```
J1K.u+N=J_WsI@Y2JtQZjsM.t.e++*]*dl`hkabhSK`hk*]*dl`hkabeSKKd
J1K.u+N=J_WsI@Y2JtQZjsM.t.eX*]*dl`hkhaeSKhSKabhSKhkKd
J1K.u+N=J_WsI@Y2JtQZ=-RhSKKjsM.t.eX*]*dl`hkheSKbhkKd
J1K.u+N=J_WsI@Y2JtQQj-#dsMC.eX*]*dl`hkheSKbhkK
J1j-#dsMC.eX*]*dl`hkyQ+Qbhkm=+Z=J_WsI@td2J
J1j-#dsMCmX*]*;l`hdyQ+Q=+Z=J_WsI@td2Jhd
J1j-#dsMCmX*]*;l`hdyQ+Q=+Z=J_WsI@td2Jh
J1j-#dsMCmX*]*;l`hdyQ+Q=+Z=@_BJsI@td2h
j-#dsMCmX*]*;l`hdyQ+Q=+Zsty%s@td2 2h
j-#dsMCmX*]*;l`hdyQ+Q=+Z@_B1.E@d2h
JQj-#dsMCmX*]*;l`hdyQ=+J@_B1.E@d2h
JyQj-#dsMCmX*]*;l`hdJ=+Q@_B1.E@d2h
j-#dsMCmX*]*;l`hdyQ=+Q@_B1.E@d2h
j-#dsMCmX*]*;l`hdyQ=+Q^_1.E@d2h
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=j-%23dsMCmX%2a%5D%2a%3Bl%60hdyQ%3D%2BQ%40_B1.E%40d2h&input=44&debug=0)

### How it works

```
j-#dsMCmX*]*;l`hdyQ=+Q^_1.E@d2h      input: Q
j-#dsMCmX*]*;l`hdyQ=+Q^_1.E@d2hdQ    implicit filling arguments

       m                        Q    for each number d from 0 to Q-1:
                           @d2           yield the square root of d.
                         .E              yield its ceiling.
                      ^_1                raise -1 to that power. this
                                         yields the desired direction.
                   =+Q                   increment Q by this amount.

               hd                        yield d+1.
              `                          yield its string representation.
             l                           yield its length.
           *;                            repeat " " for that number of times
          ]                              yield a list containing the string above.
         *       yQ                      repeat the list for Q*2 times.
                                         the Q has changed, but Q*2 is
                                         an overshoot that is high
                                         enough, so we don't have to
                                         worry about it.

        X                                in that list, replace the
                                         element with index being the
                                         number generated above
                              hd         with d+1.

      C                              transpose the resulting array.
    sM                               flatten each element.
 -#d                                 remove lines containing only spaces.
                                     (filter on truthiness of set difference with space)
j                                    join by newlines.
```

Comment: "_39: On par with Jelly_"; "_38: I have out-golfed Dennis!_" For a few hours you did, but it looks like @Dennis doesn't like to get beaten at code-golfing: [Jelly 37 bytes](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/82866/52210) ;)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Done.

Comment: Nice! xD M̶a̶y̶b̶e̶ I have a wild imagination, but now I imagine you've looked and looked in frustration for hours until you finally found this shorter solution, and now @Dennis will casually wake up and shorten his code again. (Jk, I hope you stay below Dennis!)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Tada! It's now lower than the bug-fixed version.

Answer (score 5):

## MATLAB, 148 bytes

```
n=input('');k=fix(n^.5);m=0;w=1;d=-1;for l=1:n;s=num2str(l);m(k+1,w:w+nnz(s)-1)=s;w=w+nnz(s);k=k+d;d=d*(-1)^(l^.5==fix(l^.5));end;[m(any(m,2),:),'']
```

Note that the spaces are missing in Octave, as MATLAB prints the the character indexed with `0` as a space, while octave does just omit that character.

Explanation:

```
n=input('');
k=fix(n^.5);                    %caculate starting height
m=0;w=1;d=-1;                   %initialize counters and output matrix
for l=1:n;
    s=num2str(l);
    m(k+1,w:w+nnz(s)-1)=s;      %insert current index as a string
    w=w+nnz(s);                 %current horizontal position
    k=k+d;                      %current vertical position
    d=d*(-1)^(l^.5==fix(l^.5)); %if we reached a square number, change direction
end
[m(any(m,2),:),'']              %delete all zero rows
```

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, <s>144</s> 142 bytes

```
g n|k<-take n$scanl(+)0$[1..]>>= \x->(-1)^x<$[2..2*x]=unlines[[1..n]>>= \x->show x#(k!!(x-1)==y)|y<-[minimum k..maximum k]]
s#g|g=s|1<2=' '<$s
```

Usage example:

```
*Main> putStr $ g 19
         10                  
        9  11                
 2     8     12              
1 3   7        13            
   4 6           14          
    5              15      19
                     16  18  
                       17
```

How it works:

```
s#g|g=s|1<2=' '<$s              -- # is a helper function that expects a string s
                                -- and a boolean g. It returns s if g is True, else
                                -- as many spaces as there a characters in s 

k<-take n$                      -- bind k to the first n elements of
 [1..]>>= \x->(-1)^x<$[2..2*x]  -- 2*x-1 copies of (-1)^x for each x in [1,2,3,...]
                                -- i.e. [-1, 1,1,1, -1,-1,-1,-1,-1, 1,1,1,1,1,1,1..]
 scanl(+)0                      -- build partial sums, starting with 0
                                -- i.e. [0,-1,0,1,2,1,0,-1,-2,-3,-2,-1...]
                                -- -> k is the list of y coordinates for the
                                --    numbers 1,2,3,...

 [  |y<-[minimum k..maximum k]] -- for all y coordinates in k 
      \x->show x#(k!!(x-1)==y)  -- map the # function
  [1..n]>>=                     -- over [1..n] (the x coordinates)
                                -- where # is called with
                                --  s -> a string representation of x 
                                --  g -> True if k at index x equals the current y
unlines                         -- join with newlines
```

Edit: Thanks @Lynn for two bytes!

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), 213 bytes

```
with(Math)n=>(a=[...Array(n)].map((_,i)=>n-=1+sqrt(--i)&1||-1).map((e,_,a)=>e-min(...a))).map((e,i)=>r[e][i]=++i,r=[...Array(1+max(...a))].map(_=>a.map((_,i)=>` `.repeat(1+log10(++i)))))&&r.map(a=>a.join``).join`\n`
```

Where `\n` represents a literal newline character. Explanation:

```
with(Math)                          Bring functions into scope
 n=>                                Accepts one parameter
  (a=                               Intermediate result variable
   [...Array(n)].map(               For each number 0..n-1
    (_,i)=>n-=                      Accumulate index for each number
     1+sqrt(--i)&1||-1              Calculate the direction
    ).map((e,_,a)=>e-min(...a))     Scale the smallest index to zero
  ).map((e,i)=>r[e][i]=++i,         Overwrite the padding with 1..n
   r=[...Array(1+max(...a))].map(   Calculate number of lines
    _=>a.map((_,i)=>                For each number 1..n
     ` `.repeat(1+log10(++i)))))    Calculate the padding needed
  &&r.map(a=>a.join``).join`\n`     Join everything together
```

To shorten `pow(-1,ceil(sqrt(i)))` I rewrite it as `sqrt(i-1)&1||-1` however this doesn't work for `i=0` so to fix that I add 1 but this then flips the sign of the result which is why I end up with `n-=`.

Comment: heyyy you got a gold badge! nice job! and holy smokes you almost have as much rep as I do. keep it going!

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ That's "merely" the Fanatic badge. Apparently I'm really close to getting the gold code-golf tag badge!

Comment: double holy smokes. I need to get moving XD

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 137 bytes

```
l={}
i=x=y=n=v=0
exec"v+=1;l[y]=l.get(y,'').ljust(x)+`v`;x+=len(`v`);i=-~i%-~n;y+=n%4-1;n+=2>>i*2;"*input()
for k in sorted(l):print l[k]
```

View the output on [ideone](http://ideone.com/6kjoAR).

Comment: Hm... It doesn't go on and on and on and on.

Comment: @Zizouz212 It does, ideone just has a fixed output with and automatically breaks lines that are too long.